# get the data from sqlite based on time filter

Tags: android, android-sqlite, simpledateformat, android-datepicker

I am developing app which show the list of form data, and i am adding a filter button in that list, which filter the data based on various filters, like source department and Dates(from date1 to date2).
My department and source filters are working fine but getting nothing when i select the dates.

The date in sqlite is stored in integer format, and i am trying to compare both date from sqlite with the date getting from user. but it shows nothing.

**DatabaseHelper class**

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 13;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "LoinReg.db";

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
       db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_REG_ENTRIES);
       db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_FORM_ENTRIES);
       db.execSQL(SQL_ADD_HISTORY);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        if(newVersion > oldVersion){
            db.execSQL(SQL_REG_DELETE_ENTRIES);
            db.execSQL(SQL_FORM_DELETE);
            db.execSQL(SQL_HISTORY_DELETE);
            onCreate(db);
         }
    }

    private static final String SQL_CREATE_FORM_ENTRIES =
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + FormEntry.COLUMN_TABLE_NAME +
                    " (" + FormEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                    + FormEntry.COLUMN_NAME_NAME + " TEXT,"
                    + FormEntry.COLUMN_NAME_EMAIL + " TEXT,"
                    + FormEntry.COLUMN_NAME_MOBILE + " TEXT,"
                    + FormEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ALTERNATE_NUMBER + " TEXT,"
                    + FormEntry.COLUMN_NAME_JEE + " TEXT,"
                    + COLUNM_NAME_JEERANK + " TEXT,"
                    + FormEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERCENTAGE + " TEXT,"
                    + FormEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CITY + " TEXT,"
                    + FormEntry.COLUMN_NAME_DEPT + " TEXT,"
                    + FormEntry.COLUMN_NAME_SOURCE + " TEXT,"
                    + FormEntry.TIMESTAMP + " INTEGER )";
 public boolean insertForm(String name, String email, String phone, String alternate, String jee, String jeeRank, String percentage, String city, String dept, String source){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(FormContract.FormEntry.COLUMN_NAME_NAME,name);
        values.put(FormContract.FormEntry.COLUMN_NAME_EMAIL,email);
        values.put(FormContract.FormEntry.COLUMN_NAME_MOBILE,phone);
        values.put(FormContract.FormEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ALTERNATE_NUMBER, alternate);
        values.put(FormContract.FormEntry.COLUMN_NAME_JEE,jee);
        values.put(FormContract.FormEntry.COLUNM_NAME_JEERANK,jeeRank);
        values.put(FormContract.FormEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERCENTAGE,percentage);
        values.put(FormContract.FormEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CITY,city);
        values.put(FormContract.FormEntry.COLUMN_NAME_DEPT,dept);
        values.put(FormContract.FormEntry.COLUMN_NAME_SOURCE,source);
        values.put(FormEntry.TIMESTAMP,System.currentTimeMillis());

        long newRowId = db.insert(FormContract.FormEntry.COLUMN_TABLE_NAME,null,values);

        if(newRowId == -1){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
}
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, EnquiryAdapter.OnItemClickListener {

    DbHelper mDbHelper;
    public static final String FORM_ID = "form_id";
    public static final String SQL = "sql";
    public static final String DEPT = "dept";
    public static final String SOURCE = "source";
    public static final String STARTDATE = "start_date";
    public static final String ENDDATE = "end_date";
    private static String sql, department, source;
    long StartDate, EndDate;


    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private EnquiryAdapter mAdapter;
   private EditText mStartDate, mEndDate;
    private Spinner mDeptSpinner, mSourceSpinner;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        mDbHelper = new DbHelper(this);


        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,FormActivity.class);
               startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String email = intent.getStringExtra(LoginActivity.EXTRA_EMAIL);
        TextView mEmail = headerView.findViewById(R.id.email);
        mEmail.setText(email);

        //RecyclerView Setup
        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mAdapter = new EnquiryAdapter(MainActivity.this,mDbHelper.getFormData());
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(MainActivity.this);
   }
private void showFilterDialog(){

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
        View filterDialog = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.filters,null);

        /**
         * getting the reference to the @View
         * */
        mStartDate = filterDialog.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        mEndDate = filterDialog.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        mDeptSpinner = filterDialog.findViewById(R.id.filter_dept);
        mSourceSpinner = filterDialog.findViewById(R.id.filter_source);

        AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        alertBuilder.setTitle("Filters");
        alertBuilder.setView(filterDialog);


        mStartDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDatePicker(v);
                hideKeyboard(v);

            }
        });

        mEndDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showEndDatePicker(v);
                hideKeyboard(v);
            }
        });

        /**
         * Assigning the list of items to the @Spinner.
         * */
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> deptAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.Department,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        deptAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        mDeptSpinner.setAdapter(deptAdapter);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> sourceAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.Source,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sourceAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        mSourceSpinner.setAdapter(sourceAdapter);

        /**
         * @sql statement.
         * */
        sql = "Select * from " +FormEntry.COLUMN_TABLE_NAME+ " where ";


        alertBuilder.setPositiveButton("Apply", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                Log.d("Date in milisec", String.valueOf(StartDate));
                Log.d("Date 2 in milisec", String.valueOf(EndDate));

                if(sd != null && ed != null){


                    sql = sql + FormEntry.TIMESTAMP+ " BETWEEN" + " ?" + " AND" + " ?";
                }else{
                    sql = "Select * from " +FormEntry.COLUMN_TABLE_NAME+ " where ";
                }

                department = mDeptSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                source = mSourceSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

                if(mDeptSpinner.getSelectedItem() != null){
                    sql = sql + FormEntry.COLUMN_NAME_DEPT + " = ?";
                }

                if(mSourceSpinner.getSelectedItem() != null){
                    sql = sql + " OR "+ FormEntry.COLUMN_NAME_SOURCE + " = ?";
                }

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FilterActivity.class);


               intent.putExtra(STARTDATE, StartDate);
               intent.putExtra(ENDDATE, EndDate);
                intent.putExtra(DEPT,department);
                intent.putExtra(SOURCE, source);
                intent.putExtra(SQL,sql);

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
        Button pos = alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
        pos.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        Button neg = alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
        neg.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    }
    public void showDatePicker(View view) {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new DateFragment();
        newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"datePicker");
    }
    public void showEndDatePicker(View v){
        DialogFragment dialogFragment = new EndDateFragment();
        dialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"End Date");
    }
    public void processDatePickerResult(int year,int month,int day){
        String month_string = Integer.toString(month +1);
        String day_string = Integer.toString(day);
        String year_string = Integer.toString(year);
        String dateMessage = (year_string + "-" + month_string +
                "-" + day_string);
        mStartDate.setText(dateMessage);
        StartDate = getTimeInMillis(day,month,year);

    }
    public void processEndDatePickerResult(int year, int month, int day){
        String month_string = Integer.toString(month + 1);
        String day_string  = Integer.toString(day);
        String year_String = Integer.toString(year);
        String dateMessage = (year_String + "-" + month_string +
                "-" + day_string);
        mEndDate.setText(dateMessage);
        EndDate = getTimeInMillis(day,month,year);
    }

    private void hideKeyboard(View view){
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);

    }

    public static long getTimeInMillis(int day, int month, int year) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(year, month, day);
        return calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    }
}
```

**FilterActivity.java**

```
public class FilterActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements EnquiryAdapter.OnItemClickListener {
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private EnquiryAdapter mAdapter;
    private DbHelper mDbHelper;
    public static final String FORM_ID = "form_id";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_filter);

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.filter_recyclerview);
        mDbHelper = new DbHelper(this);


        SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        intent.getExtras();

        String sql = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.SQL);
       String dept = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.DEPT);
       String source = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.SOURCE);
      long startDate = intent.getIntExtra(MainActivity.STARTDATE,0);
      long endDate = intent.getIntExtra(MainActivity.ENDDATE,0);


        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql,new String[]{String.valueOf(startDate), String.valueOf(endDate), dept, source});

        mAdapter = new EnquiryAdapter(FilterActivity.this, cursor);

        //RecyclerView Setup
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        //mAdapter = new EnquiryAdapter(FilterActivity.this,mDbHelper.getFormData());
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(FilterActivity.this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailedActivity.class);
        int id = EnquiryAdapter.id;
        intent.putExtra(FORM_ID,id);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can write SQL Query for this get filtered data

Comment: what do mean by write Query?

Comment: That’s very much code. Please (for this question and your future ones) see if you can boil it down to [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue appears to be that there would be **no logical conjunction** of the BETWEEN clause and the other parts of the WHERE clause in the generated SQL.

That is **if** the variable **sd** and **ed** are both not null (in the code provided they don't appear to be declared or instantiated) and thus that the SQL is to include the BETWEEN clause, there would be no AND or OR (I guess the former would be required). SO the SQL passed via the Intent Extra would be along the lines of :-

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE your_timestamp_column BETWEEN ? AND ? your_dept_column = ? OR your_source_column = ?
```

Whilst it should be (assuming **AND**) :-

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE your_timestamp_column BETWEEN ? AND ? 
    AND ( -- <<<<<<<<<<<< MISSING CONJUNCTION
        your_dept_column = ? OR your_source_column = ?
    )
```

- where your_table, your_timestamp_column, your_dept_column and your_source_column are the identifiers resolved from your variables.

At a guess you code could be along the lines of :-

```
            String time_filter_end_char = ""; //<<<<<<<<<< NO ) at end if no time_filter
            String sd = String.valueOf(StartDate); //<<<<<<<<<< ?????????
            String ed = String.valueOf(EndDate); //<<<<<<<<<< ??????????
            if(sd != null && ed != null && sd.length() >  0 && ed.length() > 0 ){
                time_filter_end_char = ")";
                sql = sql + FormEntry.TIMESTAMP+ " BETWEEN" + " ?" + " AND" + " ? AND("; //<<<<<<<<<< CONJUNCTION ADDED
            }
            //<<<<<<<<<< else construct/clause REMOVED as it does nothing
            department = mDeptSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            source = mSourceSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

            if(mDeptSpinner.getSelectedItem() != null){
                sql = sql + FormEntry.COLUMN_NAME_DEPT + " = ?";
            }

            if(mSourceSpinner.getSelectedItem() != null){
                sql = sql + " OR "+ FormEntry.COLUMN_NAME_SOURCE + " = ?";
            }
            sql = sql + time_filter_end_char;
```

However, if the above would be an issue if dept or source were both null or empty.

So perhaps more correct code would be something like :-

```
    String sd = String.valueOf(StartDate);
    String ed = String.valueOf(EndDate);
    String department = mDeptSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String source = mSourceSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + FormEntry.COLUMN_TABLE_NAME; //<<<<<<< no filtering
    String time_filter = "";
    String department_filter = "";
    String source_filter = "";
    if (sd != null && ed != null && sd.length() > 0 && ed.length() > 0) {
        time_filter = FormEntry.TIMESTAMP + " BETWEEN" + " ?" + " AND" + " ? ";
    }
    if (department != null && department.length() > 0) {
        department_filter = FormEntry.COLUMN_NAME_DEPT + " = ?";
    }
    if (source != null && source.length() > 0) {
        source_filter = FormEntry.COLUMN_NAME_SOURCE + " = ?";
    }
    String dept_source_conjunction = "";
    if (department_filter.length() > 0 && source_filter.length() > 0) {
        dept_source_conjunction = " OR ";
    }
    if (time_filter.length() > 0 || department_filter.length() > 0 || source_filter.length() > 0) {
        sql = sql + " WHERE ";
    }
    String end_dept_source_char = "";
    if (time_filter.length() > 0) {
        sql = sql + time_filter;
        if (department_filter.length() > 0 || source_filter.length() > 0) {
            sql = sql + " AND ";
            if (dept_source_conjunction.length() > 0) {
                sql = sql + "(";
                end_dept_source_char = ")";
            }
        }
    }
    sql = sql + department_filter + dept_source_conjunction + source_filter  + end_dept_source_char;
```

## Testing :-

The following adaptation of the above was used to test the code :-

```
private String testit(String StartDate, String EndDate, String mDS, String mSS) {
        //String sd = String.valueOf(StartDate);
        //String ed = String.valueOf(EndDate);
        String sd = StartDate; //<<<<<<<<<< FOR TESTING
        String ed = EndDate; //<<<<<<<<<< FOR TESTING
        //String department = mDeptSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        //String source = mSourceSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String department = mDS; //<<<<<<<<<< FOR TESTING
        String source = mSS; //<<<<<<<<<< FOR TESTING
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + FormEntry.COLUMN_TABLE_NAME; //<<<<<<< no filtering
        String time_filter = "";
        String department_filter = "";
        String source_filter = "";
        if (sd != null && ed != null && sd.length() > 0 && ed.length() > 0) {
            time_filter = FormEntry.TIMESTAMP + " BETWEEN" + " ?" + " AND" + " ? ";
        }
        if (department != null && department.length() > 0) {
            department_filter = FormEntry.COLUMN_NAME_DEPT + " = ?";
        }
        if (source != null && source.length() > 0) {
            source_filter = FormEntry.COLUMN_NAME_SOURCE + " = ?";
        }
        String dept_source_conjunction = "";
        if (department_filter.length() > 0 && source_filter.length() > 0) {
            dept_source_conjunction = " OR ";
        }
        if (time_filter.length() > 0 || department_filter.length() > 0 || source_filter.length() > 0) {
            sql = sql + " WHERE ";
        }
        String end_dept_source_char = "";
        if (time_filter.length() > 0) {
            sql = sql + time_filter;
            if (department_filter.length() > 0 || source_filter.length() > 0) {
                sql = sql + " AND ";
                if (dept_source_conjunction.length() > 0) {
                    sql = sql + "(";
                    end_dept_source_char = ")";
                }
            }
        }
        sql = sql + department_filter + dept_source_conjunction + source_filter  + end_dept_source_char;
        return sql;
    }
```

Then the following was used :-

```
    Log.d("TEST2", testit(null,null,null,null)); //<<<<<<<<<< no filter
    Log.d("TEST1",testit("1111111111","2222222222",null,null)); // time filter only
    Log.d("TEST3", testit("1111111111","2222222222","d1","s1")); // full filter
    Log.d("TEST4",testit("1111111111","2222222222",null,"s1")); // time and source
    Log.d("TEST5",testit("1111111111","2222222222","d1","")); // time and dept
```

The result being :-

```
D/TEST2: SELECT * FROM your_table_name
D/TEST1: SELECT * FROM your_table_name WHERE your_timestamp_column BETWEEN ? AND ? 
D/TEST3: SELECT * FROM your_table_name WHERE your_timestamp_column BETWEEN ? AND ?  AND (your_department_column = ? OR your_source_column = ?)
D/TEST4: SELECT * FROM your_table_name WHERE your_timestamp_column BETWEEN ? AND ?  AND your_source_column = ?
D/TEST5: SELECT * FROM your_table_name WHERE your_timestamp_column BETWEEN ? AND ?  AND your_department_column = ?
```